# display php array data as lines

Tags: php, arrays

I have this type of array data

(its just a part of the original array)

```
Array
(
    [out] => Array
        (
            [in1] => Array
                (
                    [d1] => data1
                    [d2] => data2
                    [d3] => data3
                    [d4] => data4
                    [d5] => data5
                    [d6] => data6
                    [d7] => data7
                    [d8] => data8
                )

            [in2] => Array
                (
                    [d9] => Array
                        (
                            [b1] => data9
                            [b2] => data10
                        )

                    [d10] => Array
                        (
                            [b1] => data11
                            [b2] => data12
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

how to display it like this...

```
out.in1.d1=data1
out.in1.d2=data2
out.in1.d3=data3
out.in1.d4=data4
out.in1.d5=data5
out.in1.d6=data6
out.in1.d7=data7
out.in1.d8=data8
out.in2.d9.b1=data9
out.in2.d9.b2=data10
out.in2.d10.b1=data11
out.in2.d11.b2=data12
```

I've tried this

```
function test_print($data, $key)
{
    echo "$key='$data'\n";
}
array_walk_recursive($array, 'test_print');
```

but it only prints the last key
like this

d1=data1
d2=data2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure you can do this with a built-in PHP function. But here's a simple recursive function that will give you what you want:

```
function recursePrint($array, $prefix = '') {
    foreach($array AS $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            recursePrint($value, $prefix . $key . ".");
        } else {
            echo $prefix . $key . "=" . $value . "\n";
        }
    }
}

recursePrint($array);
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/VLJVU

Comment: I upped yours *(that sounds wrong...)* and downed the other guy's answer because it was incorrect - was probably spite :/

Comment: @Emissary yeah he probably thought I downvoted him (I didn't) and was retaliating. Oh well.